# Python icalendar not recognising key

Tags: python, parsing, icalendar

---

Hi There,

I'm new to parsing iCal and was wondering why I am getting the following error.

I have the following iCal format and I'm using the icalendar library for python to parse it. Unfortunately the ATTENDEE key is not being recognised and will only be recognised when placing a tab beside the new line. How come this is the case? The iCal validator claims this is valid iCal

```
 BEGIN:VCALENDAR
 PRODID:-// Example classroom timetable
 VERSION:2.0
 BEGIN:VEVENT
 ATTENDEE;CN=91827364;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED;DELEGATED-FROM
 ="mailto:teststudent@class.com":mailto:teststudent@class.com
 ATTENDEE;CN=81726354;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED;DELEGATED-FROM 
 ="mailto:teststudent2@class.com":mailto:teststudent2@class.com
 ATTENDEE;CN=31602424;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED;DELEGATED-FROM
 ="mailto:teststudent3@class.com":mailto:teststudent3@class.com
 ATTENDEE;CN=40049549;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED;DELEGATED-FROM
 ="mailto:teststudent4@class.com":mailto:teststudent4@class.com
 CREATED:20180730T220042Z
 DESCRIPTION:MA1234 - MATHEMATIC\n\n Event Type:LECTURE\n\n 
   Lecturer(s):DR.1\n\n Location(s):CLASSROOM 3
 DTEND:20170926T170000Z
 DTSTAMP:20180730T220042Z
 DTSTART:20170926T160000Z
 LAST-MODIFIED:20170601T105200Z
 LOCATION:CLASSROOM3
 SEQUENCE:0
 SUMMARY:MA1234 - MATHEMATICS
 UID:0000924617001-1726920-XXXXXXXXXX@class.com
 END:VEVENT
 END:VCALENDAR
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This validator https://icalendar.org/validator.html#results (after removing spaces from cut & paste of file)  says:
'UID values must not contain data that might indentify a user, host, domain or other sensitive information near line # 3'.   which is interesting - I think it's the @class.com it does not like.  I'm learning!  See https://icalendar.org/New-Properties-for-iCalendar-RFC-7986/5-3-uid-property.html

Always run your ics file through as many of the ics validators as you can find  as they pickup different things sometimes & Fixing the errors sometimes fixes problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lines longer than 75 characters must be folded in a specific way.. CRLF immediately followed by a single linear white-space character (i.e.,
SPACE or HTAB)

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.1